# Numpy and matplotlib Import errors

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have installed matplotlib 1.2.0 and numpy 1.6.2 for python 2.7.4 
And I get the below import errors when i try to run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\IQ_polar.py", line 16, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numerictypes as nt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 429, in <module>
    _set_up_aliases()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 412, in _set_up_aliases
    allTypes[alias] = allTypes[t]
KeyError: 'timedelta'
```

Part of the code that is generating this error is

```
import math
import struct
import binascii
from ast import literal_eval
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import scipy as sp
```

I feel its something to do with the numpy package. What am i missing?!

Comment: Please show us your code which generate this error. Show us the file `D:\Python\IQ_polar.py`.

Comment: showed it in the question now

Comment: I suspect that this might be due to version incompatibility between numpy 1.6.2 and matplotlib 1.2.0 (numpy 1.6.2 is rather old). Could you try updating to a more recent version?

Comment: matplotlib 1.2.0 is _also_ rather old.

Answer (score 0):

Python and python packages downloaded from the site mentioned below work just fine!
https://www.enthought.com/downloads/